# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm having this problem, I'm new to development, could someone help me, I think it has to do with fetch.

```
import { User } from '../context/auth';
import { API_URL } from '../config';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

export const login = async (username: string): Promise<User> => {

    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username })
    });

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        Alert.alert('Error while signing in');  // Network request failed
    }

    console.log(response);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this updated code, if the response status is not **200 (success)**, an error is thrown using **throw new Error()**.

```
export const login = async (username: string): Promise<User> => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username })
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Error while signing in');
    }
};
```

Handle the promise rejection appropriately:

```
try {
    const user = await login(username);
    // Handle successful login
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    Alert.alert('Error while signing in');
}
```